# How to Modify Data Grid Cell Back Ground from code behind?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I would like to modify the background of Data Grid Cell, but only Row Header Value and Column Header Value information was available.

I have tried to implement the approach in the below link, but nothing worked.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63974f4f-d9ee-45af-8499-42f29cbc22ae/grabing-controls-from-a-datagrid?forum=wpf

How to get the Data grid Cell Object by using Row Header and Column Header value.?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways by which you are reaching your DataGridCell. Eg; By clicking a cell with mouse, or using a Row index and Column index or something else.

1>  If you clicking a cell, then you have to traverse the visual tree upwards. And use the following approach :

[DETECTING THE COLUMN, CELL AND ROW THAT HAS BEEN CLICKED](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html) .

2> You can use following approach :

```
        object item = dgrdInvoice.CurrentCell.Item;
        DataGridRow row = dgrdInvoice.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
        DataGridRow row = dgrdInvoice.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        dgrdInvoice.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(row);
```

Note : Approach differs depending upon your particular scenario. As finding cell in general needs visual tree traversing.

3> For all other general scenarios, you can refer here : 
[Programmatically Selecting and Focusing a Row or Cell in a DataGrid](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx)